# Django field doesn't remain incremented even after calling save()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've searched all over and couldn't find an answer for this. I really can't understand why this doesn't work, especially since it works in other projects. Anyway, I'm trying to increment a model field by 1 when a user gets a question correct. I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 3.5, with factory_boy for creating test data.

Here's the views.py function:

```
def check_answer(request):
    front = request.POST.get('front')
    userAnswer = request.POST.get('ans')
    answerCards = Card.objects.filter(front=front)
    for ans in answerCards:
        if ans.back == userAnswer:
            ans.score += 1
            ans.save() # at this point calling print(ans.score) will return 1
            return HttpResponse('correct')
    answerCards.update(score=F('score') - 1) # using print statements I know it isn't hitting this line
    return HttpResponse('wrong')
```

Here's the relevant models.py code:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    front = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    back = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.front + ' - ' + self.back
```

Here's the relevant tests.py code:

```
class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user%d' % n)
    password = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'pass%d' % n)


class DeckFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Deck

    author = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    title = fuzzy.FuzzyText()
    description = fuzzy.FuzzyText()


class CardFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Card

    front = fuzzy.FuzzyText()
    back = fuzzy.FuzzyText()
    deck = factory.SubFactory(DeckFactory)
    score = random.randint(-20, 10)


class TestNotecardViews(TestCase):

    def test_add_score_to_card(self):
        # this test passes
        card = CardFactory(score=0)
        card.score += 1
        card.save()
        self.assertEqual(1, card.score)

    def test_check_answer(self):
        deck = DeckFactory.create()
        card = CardFactory.create(front='test',
                                  back='tset',
                                  deck=deck,
                                  score=0)
        # test correct answer
        data = {
                'front': card.front,
                'ans': 'tset',
        }
        resp = self.client.post(reverse('check_answer'), data=data)
        self.assertContains(resp, 'correct', 1) # this test passes
        self.assertEqual(card.score, 1) # this test fails
```

What's especially frustrating is that the value *does* change, it just doesn't stay that way after the function that changed it returns, even after calling save().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload your local version of `card` back from the database after you call the view. Otherwise they have nothing to do with each other, and `card` has no way of knowing that the db has been updated.

```
resp = self.client.post(reverse('check_answer'), data=data)
card = Card.objects.get(id=card.id)
self.assertEqual(card.score, 1)
```

Comment: That worked! Didn't realize you have to reload it like that. Now I know, thanks!